# How to find simple word in Java file?

Tags: java, regex

I need help. I'm beginning programmer, I try to make program with regular expression.
I try to find every **life** word in my file. I have code like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class myClass {

    public int howManyWord () {
        int count = 0;      
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/myFile.txt"));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("life").matcher(line);
                while (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println("found");
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return count;       
    }
}
```

That works. I try to change this because when I'm searching my word and when compilator find something like this "lifelife" count is 2.
What should I change?

Sorry for my English but help me, please.

Comment: Try changing "life" to "\\blife\\b"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"(?<=^|\\W)life(?=$|\\W)"` will find words "life" but not "lifelife" or "xlife".

Comment: Thanks man! Thats answer. Could you tell me how can I ignore **life** in comments? Like: `// life` and `/* life */`. TY :)

Comment: @Anthony well, ignoring line comments can be done with a "look behind". Block comments are worse...

Answer (score 1):

Use `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\blife\\b");` and set the pattern once before the while loop.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class myClass {

public int howManyWord () {
    int count = 0;      
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/myFile.txt"));
        String line = "";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\blife\\b"); // compile pattern only once
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println("found");
                count++;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return count;       
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how should I change that code to ignore **life** in comments?